# How to turn something negative to positive in SOP?

Tags: phd, statement-of-purpose

I did not pass my PhD candidacy twice and planning to apply at other institutes to pursue my PhD dream. In that case, should I mention my failure in candidacy to my SOP? If yes, how can I convert that to something positive to make my application impactful. Please suggest. Thank you

Comment: Why did you fail your PhD candidacy?

Comment: You can choose not to mention it.

Comment: or, you can describe what have you learned from that negative experience?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist probably not a good idea. The truth is bound to come out eventually.

Comment: I would argue not mentioning something as critical as failing a candidacy exam twice is a lie by omission and should be addressed.

Comment: The failing itself is obviously negative. It might be possible that you drew something positive from these experiences, but that will entirely depend on the situations themselves. If I was the hiring PI, I would mostly be interested in any finished projects you have under your belt.

Comment: The above commenters are wrong.  There is no obligation to mention how you did on candidacy exams in your SOP.   It may or may not come out eventually, but this is irrelevant.  Your candidacy exams just have limited relevance to your SOP, which is about why you should be admitted.

Comment: If you failed twice, that should tell you something.  You shouldn't continue if you lack the technical background.  You are setting up yourself for failure.

Answer (score -1):

Did you graduate with a master's degree? If yes, then one option is to avoid discussing this altogether. You can approach this (honestly) as "I earned my master's degree and now I want to get my PhD." They may guess what happened (or your letters of recommendation may spill the beans), but it still lets you avoid dwelling on a negative in your SOP.

Your other option (and only option, if you left without a degree) is to provide your own perspective on what happened. "Turning a negative into a positive" is probably too much to hope for, but you can take some of the sting out of the negative. I would suggest to: acknowledge the failure, explain what went wrong, and explain why things will be different next time. You can do this *very* concisely -- just a few sentences.